# Angular Material Table - Select a Row Using Code

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am developing an Angular 5 application and have an Angular Material Table displaying some data. I want the user to be able to select a graphical item, outside of the Table, and in the `click` function select the appropriate row in my Table.

I tried creating a `ViewChild` of the `Mat-Table` but I couldn't seem to get a reference to the selected row. The ` definition doesn't seem to offer any clues either. Here is my Table:

```
        <!-- Table -->
        <div id="table-container" style="height: 240px; width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
          <mat-table #table
                     class="mat-table"
                     [dataSource]="dataSource"
                     style="height: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);">

            <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
                The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->
            <!-- Device Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="DeviceName">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Device </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.deviceName}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Location Name Column -->
            <ng-container matColumnDef="LocationName">
              <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Location </mat-header-cell>
              <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item"> {{item.locationName}} </mat-cell>
            </ng-container>

            <!-- Header Row -->
            <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef=""></mat-header-row>
            <!--<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>-->
            <!-- Row Definition -->
            <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let index=index;"
                     [ngClass]="setRowClass(index)"
                     (click)="onClickRow(row, $event, index)"
                     (mouseenter)="onMouseEnterRow(index)"
                     (mouseleave)="onMouseLeaveRow(index)">
            </mat-row>

          </mat-table>
        </div>
```

Any suggestions would be extremely welcome. Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for a flow that looks something like this: `user clicks on graphical item, perhaps a button` -> `specific row in table is selected as a result`? If that's the case, you could give your row a `selected` key, so that in your `[ngClass]` in the `mat-row` definition, you could do something like `[ngClass]="{'select-row': row.selected}"` to give the row a graphical difference once it's been selected. As for the functionality of it being selected, it depends on what you want to happen once a row is selected.

Comment: You are correct in the flow, click button -> row becomes selected. After the user has clicked, say the button, I want the user to be able to click another item on the screen which will update data for the currently selected row. I will review your suggestion once I am back in the code and reply later with any results. Thanks